.NET MAUI app solution: Error (active) APT2000 expected reference but got (raw string) #000000
I have a problem with building a .NET MAUI app solution.
I get the following error messages when I build the solution (in Visual Studio):

res/values/values.xml(6): error APT2000: expected reference but got
(raw string) #000000. [C:\Dev\QIT\QFS\QFSMobileMAUI
\QUniversalMAUISolution\Qit.QUniversal.Controls\Qit.QUniversal.Controls.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android34.0]
res/values/values.xml(6): error APT2000:
[C:\Dev\QIT\QFS\QFSMobileMAUI\QUniversalMAUISolution\Qit.QUniversal.Controls
Qit.QUniversal.Controls.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android34.0]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(156,3):
error APT2062: failed linking references.
[C:\Dev\QIT\QFS\QFSMobileMAUI\QUniversalMAUISolution\Qit.QUniversal.Controls\Qit.QU
niversal.Controls.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android34.0]
C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(156,3):
error APT2062:
[C:\Dev\QIT\QFS\QFSMobileMAUI\QUniversalMAUISolution\Qit.QUniversal.Controls\Qit.QUniversal.Controls.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-android34.0]

I can't really find out what the root cause of this error is.
I found a similar stack overflow question about this problem:
Build fails with error: expected reference but got (raw string) #000000
.. and I have tried this answer:

#000000 find for this in your style.xml

<item name="background">#000000</item>


then create an entry for this color in color.xml and then use its
string reference.

<color name="black">#000000</color>

<item name="background">@color/black</item>


it wont give this error anymore.

But this didn't solve it. I don't have a style.xml file in my Android platform folder:

And I don't have the color: #000000 in my 'general' Styles.xml file:

The (Android) colors.xml file I use is as followed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#512BD4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2B0B98</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2B0B98</color>
</resources>

I thought of these possible (root) causes of this error:

A missing reference in one of the projects <- Not likely

The (MAUI) Frame control? <- Not the cause

Other build errors in the code which don't show up?  <- This is the most likely cause. But I have solved all other build errors and I still get the errors described above.

Missing images (which are used in the controls) in the main MAUI recource folder? <- Not likely

The target Android Framework. <- I can only use Target Android framework 14.0 (API Level 34).

An (accent) color used in one of the MAUI XAMl views which does not exist in the Android colors.xml? <- I can't find such a color. I don't use the color: #000000. I get these kind of warning messages in my solution though:



Can this have something to do with this error?
The target Android framework I use is: Android 14.0 (API Level 34) and the Target .NET runtime I use is 8.0.
Does anybody know what causes this error and how to solve it?

Did you get this error if you create and build a new maui project? In addition, you can create the  styles.xml in the \Platforms\Android\Resources\values manually.

Thank you. Ok I have created a whole new (Empthy) MAUI Project (solution) and build it (Android target framework: 14.0) and then I don't get this error. Yes I have created the styles.xml and have tried to add the color item reference (see answer from similar problem) in it but this didn't solve it.

Did you use any third party nuget package? I never met this error before.

Thank you! Yes I noticed that I still had a reference to:  Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms in my Qit.QUniversal.Controls project that caused this error. After I removed this reference this error didn't occur anymore.

You are welcome. Glad to know you have resolved it.

I found out what caused this error.
In one of my projects (Qit.QUniversal.Controls) I still had a reference to: Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms

After I removed this reference this error didn't occur anymore.
This solved this specific error.

Thanks for your update, you can accept your own question
